# One file for all virtual, downloadable product variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Does any know if it is possible to have one file download for all variations of a product? OR a better way to setup what I need to achieve?!

To explain, I've built a type foundry site for a client and they have multiple weights and license combinations, but they effect only the price rather than what is downloaded.

I've used attributes & variations to map this out, but am wondering if there is a simpler way, as there's currently 48 variations for each weight. Obviously this poses an administration and maintenance nightmare, considering they all require the same file! I was considering programmatically adding the file reference, but again this isn't plausible going forward.

[image: As you can see, there are many variations - but they all result in the same download]

[image: Adding a file to each variation is laborious and implausible going forward]

Whilst I'm a competent freelance developer of 10 years, I rarely, if ever, go near the configuration of eCommerce sites!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: please edit your question and add a exemple of a simplification your desire

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had given a clear explanation, I'm editing now to add screenshots. I can't give code examples as this isn't code specific. Thanks!